# How do i ignore bad data when reading from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

To be more specific, I am given this input:

```
Mo  17 30   15  
Sa  9 00    30  
Tu  3 30    45  
Sq    
Fr  21 01   60
```

The letters represent a day of the week and the numbers denote time (in military time) and length of the call (in minutes).

The code works perfectly as long as valid data is entered, but, like in this case, when Sq is entered the loop breaks down. heres my logic so far

```
while(!instream.eof()){

        instream>>c1>>c2;
        day = checker(c1, c2);
        cout<<c1<<" "<<c2<<endl;

    if(day == 0){
        instream.ignore(100,'/n');
        instream>>c1>>c2;
        day = checker(c1, c2);
    }
```

`instream` is my file object, `c1` and `c2` are of type `char`, and the function `checker` checks the chars to see if the combination of the 2 is a valid day of the week. If not, it returns 0.

From what I understand, `instream.ignore` with those arguments will skip at most 100 characters, or until a new line is found. The problem is, after this statement runs, the loop terminates.
I also might have some random `cout`s or `outstream`s in there, I was just checking stuff.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int checker(char a, char b);
void main(){
    ifstream instream;
    ofstream outstream;

    instream.open("infile.txt");
    outstream.open("outfile.txt");

    double cost = 0, realtime;
        int check = 0, day = 0, hour, min, time, i = 1;
    char c1, c2, c3;

    while(!instream.eof()){

        instream>>c1>>c2;
        day = checker(c1, c2);
        cout<<c1<<" "<<c2<<endl;

    if(day == 0){
        instream.ignore(100,'/n');
        instream>>c1>>c2;
        day = checker(c1, c2);
        }
    instream>>hour>>min>>time;
    realtime = 1.0*hour + min/60.0;

    if(day == 1 && (realtime < 7 || realtime > 21)){
        cost = 0.15 * time;
        outstream<<"The cost of call " << i << " is $" << cost <<endl;
        i++;
    }
    else if(day == 1 && (realtime >= 7 || realtime <= 21)){
        cost = 0.30 * time;
        outstream<<"The cost of call " << i << " is $" << cost <<endl;
        i++;
    }
    else if(day == 2){
        cost = 0.10 * time;
        outstream<<"The cost of call " << i << " is $" << cost <<endl;
        i++;
    }
    outstream<<" "<<hour<<endl;
        outstream<<" "<<min<<endl;
    outstream<<" "<<time<<endl;
    outstream<<" "<<i<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"The program has completed its task"<<endl;
    instream.close();
    outstream.close();
    
}
int checker(char a, char b){
    int day2 = 0;
    if(a == 'M' && b == 'o' || a == 'm'&& b == 'O' || a == 'm'&& b == 'o' || a == 'M'&& b == 'O'){
    day2 = 1;
    }
     
    else if(a == 'T'&& b == 'u' || a == 't'&& b == 'U' || a == 't'&& b == 'u' || a == 'T'&& b == 'u'){
    day2 = 1;
    }
     
    else if(a == 'W'&& b == 'e' || a == 'w'&& b == 'E' || a == 'w'&& b == 'e' || a == 'W'&& b == 'E'){
    day2 = 1;
    }
     
    else if(a == 'T'&& b == 'h' || a == 't'&& b == 'H' || a == 't'&& b == 'h' || a == 'T'&& b == 'H'){
    day2 = 1;
    }
     
    else if(a == 'F'&& b == 'r' || a == 'f'&& b == 'R' || a == 'f'&& b == 'r' || a == 'F'&& b == 'R'){
    day2 = 1;
    }
     
    else if((a == 'S'&& b == 'a') || (a == 's'&& b == 'A') || (a == 's'&& b == 'a') || (a == 'S'&& b == 'A')){
    day2 = 2;
    }
    else if((a == 'S'&& b == 'u') || (a == 's'&& b == 'U') || (a == 's'&& b == 'u') || (a == 'S'&& b == 'U')){
    day2 = 2;
    }
    else
    day2 = 0;

    return day2;
}

--939345676
```

Edit: I agree 100% that I should be reading it as a line and parsing the string, but I'm currently taking a programming class, and we are told we can only use functions/loops/methods that have been discussed in lectures.

Comment: When trying to read in a file, you typically want to check `while(instream.good()) {...}` instead of `while (!instream.eof()) {...}`.

Comment: I suppose that the line `instream.ignore(100,'/n');` should be `instream.ignore(100,'\n');`.

Answer (score 2):

Use cin.getline instead to get the entire line as a string, and then parse the string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your loop breaks is this statement,

instream.ignore(100,'/n');

This means "Ignore 100 chars or /n whichever comes first". So when your program skips 100 chars it reaches end of file and your loop breaks as eof() is reached. Also you are using wrong char for LINE END. Its not "/n". It is "\n" (back slash), and to represent it in C code you have to write "\n".

But your algorithm needs considerable improvements. Try reading complete line and then check if the first two chars in that line are valid. Otherwise ignore that line.
Also in you checker function. It would be better if you convert both chars to upper case and then check if they are valid, so that you don't have to check all combination. when you apply toupper() function to "mo" or "Mo" or "mO" or "MO", the result will be MO in all cases and then you can compare it in 1 check only.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem with your logic is that if two consecutive bad days are entered, what happens?

I would suggest using ignore, then using `continue` to retry your loop (instead of reading the date and continuing blindly).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just wrap it up in a "try/catch" block?